# Can I use automator to launch a keystroke when program is idle

Tags: automator

Can I use automator to launch a keystroke (cmd+R) when program PremierePro CS6 is idle for 1 minute. This keystroke would start program to Render videofiles.
Many Thanks, Jan.

Comment: You might get better answers if you don't restrict the solution space to Automator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how well it would work, but you could try running something like this in AppleScript Editor.

```
repeat
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
        set p to properties of UI elements of UI elements
        delay 10
        if properties of UI elements of UI elements is p then
            set frontmost to true
            keystroke "r" using command down
            --return
            delay 20
        end if
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks, it works almost perfect. Now it puts the process upfront after a delay of 10 seconds, can this be changed in : after "inactivity" of 10 seconds ?

Comment: or after 1minute of "keyboard inactivity" ?

Comment: I don't know any way to really see if an application hasn't been used. `properties of UI elements of UI elements` just checks if properties like the positions of windows have been changed.

Comment: no problem, many thans, anyway.

Comment: one last question, I tried to add a "keystroke" cmd+h to hide the program after it did cmd+r. but it seems only to do cmd+h.any idea what i did wrong ?

Comment: I made a mistake, it works fine now. Many thanks for your help!